# Is there any real difference between these two code snippets?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference in the following code snippets?
They both work, would one be considered better or cleaner than the other?

```
someFunc(){

    var ret;                

    if(thisBoolean === true){                   
     ret =  some value

    }
    else{
       ret =  some other value        
    }
    return ret;  
}
```

And

```
someFunc(){

    if(thisBoolean === true){                   
     return some value

    }
    else{
      return some other value        
    }
}
```

Comment: They're identical; which one you use is up to personal preference.

Comment: Define 'difference' and 'better/cleaner'. In what context? Performance? Maintainability? Length?

Comment: The first allows for further processing of `ret` after the `if`/`else`, if you need to add more logic later. (Suppose `ret` is a number, and you need to add `1` to it regardless of the `if`/`else` path. In the second case, you'd need to make two changes; the first you only make one.) Otherwise, they're the same.

Comment: @MeanGreen Everyone else understood the question.

Comment: @Daft odd, because my definition of 'better' is probably not the same as yours or his. What happened to asking SMART questions?

Comment: @MeanGreen Caps lock is a great way to get a point across. It's like shouting, it always makes you look very smart indeed.

Comment: @Daft I used uppercase because I'm referring to the acronym http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria. I fail to see what I've done to earn your negative comments?

Comment: @MeanGreen haha, woops. My apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally go with the second; you return when you mean to return, it is clear that no further changes are made before return. By contrast in the second, you could have a final check or transformation on `ret`.

The only caveat is when the return involves some operation that you do in both branches, in which case DRY would suggest you follow the first pattern.

People vary on the ternary operator, but I quite like the functional style of it:

```
var someFunc = function(isSpecial) { 
      return isSpecial ? specialVal : ordinaryVal;
};
```

Comment: Cheers Phil, appreciate the informative response.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your coding style. **I** would have done

```
someFunc(){
  return thisBoolean ? 'some value' : 'some other value'
}
```

So it all depends on what you want or how you code.

Answer (score 0):

They will produce the same output. They are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

they will produce the same output but, the first one, with just one return will make your debugging easy.